# Policy in freeradius isnt running

Tags: freeradius, radius

Im building a freeradius server for authenticate.
I have a problem with `policy.conf`:
The `policy.conf` was loaded in `radius.conf` as `$INCLUDE policy.conf` but the content of this file didn't work.

I tested by login with 'test' user but it didn't reject. Can someone help me about this, thanks very much.

```
policy {
    #
    #   Forbid all EAP types.
    #
    if (User-Name == 'test'){
            reject
    }

    forbid_eap {
        if (EAP-Message) {
            reject
        }
    }

    #
    #   Forbid all non-EAP types outside of an EAP tunnel.
    #
    permit_only_eap {
        if (!EAP-Message) {
            #  We MAY be inside of a TTLS tunnel.
            #  PEAP and EAP-FAST require EAP inside of
            #  the tunnel, so this check is OK.
            #  If so, then there MUST be an outer EAP message.
            if (!"%{outer.request:EAP-Message}") {
                reject
            }
        }
    }

    #
    #   Forbid all attempts to login via realms.
    #
    deny_realms {
        if (User-Name =~ /@|\\/) {
            reject
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your error stack.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give your policy a name (like the other policies in the policy section).

```
policy {
    reject_test {
        if (User-Name == 'test'){
            reject
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to list the policy in one of the sections (`authorize`, `authenticate`, `post-auth` etc...) of one of the virtual servers.

See the [concepts page](https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Concepts) in the FreeRADIUS wiki for some basic details about which sections get run and where.

If you're using a stock configuration you'll likely need to edit `raddb/sites-available/default`.

In this case you probably want to add your policy to the `authorize section`.

```
authorize {
    reject_test
    ...
}
```

You don't actually need to define policies in order to run use the policy language, you could insert your condition directly into the authorize section.

```
authorize {
    if (User-Name == 'test'){
        reject
    }
}
```